# Oracle PL/SQL writing on websocket

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, websocket, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am writing an application which required PL/SQL send the message to WebSocket. Currently, I am using UTL_TCP in order to connect with WebSocket.

My WebSocket server has different type of client, JavaScript, PHP, JAVA, Oracle PL/SQL. I am able to connect and send the message to all others except Oracle PL/SQL.

Any suggestion is appreciated,

Here is my PL/Sql code.

```
DECLARE
CONN         UTL_TCP.CONNECTION;
RETVAL       BINARY_INTEGER;
L_RESPONSE   VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
L_TEXT  VARCHAR2(1000);    
content varchar2(4000) := '{"clientSession": "rmmd5kfcbv7i3h0jeel57a4o62","message": "Hi from oracle", "msgClient": "php"}';
BEGIN
 CONN := UTL_TCP.OPEN_CONNECTION(
    REMOTE_HOST   => '127.0.0.1',
    REMOTE_PORT   => 5050,
    TX_TIMEOUT    => 10,
    charset     => 'UTF-8'
);
 RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'GET / HTTP/1.1');
RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Upgrade: websocket');
RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Connection: Upgrade');
RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Host: localhost');
RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Origin: localhost');
RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Sec-WebSocket-Key: TyPfhFqWTjuw8eDAxdY8xg==');
RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13');
RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Content-Type: application/json');
RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Content-Length: ' || length(content));
RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Content: ' || content);
RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN, '{"clientSession": "plloua8kg6nuqg53l2sv7m6do2","message": "Hi from oracle", "msgClient": "ora"}');

RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN);
UTL_TCP.FLUSH(CONN);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Response from Socket Server : ' || L_RESPONSE);
UTL_TCP.CLOSE_CONNECTION(CONN);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101,SQLERRM);
    UTL_TCP.CLOSE_CONNECTION(CONN);
 END;
```

Comment: "... except Oracle PL/SQL". Not that I know the answer, but - what happens? Any error? If so, which one?

Comment: So basically I am able to connect to WebSocket by faking header information, But can't read the message. in my case JSON string '{"clientSession": "plloua8kg6nuqg53l2sv7m6do2","message": "Hi from oracle", "msgClient": "ora"}'

Comment: Try to use: utl_http.begin_request, utl_http.set_header, utl_http.set_body_charset, utl_http.write_text, utl_http.get_response, utl_http.read_text, utl_http.end_response.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion,  is it going to work for ws://127.0.0.1  not http://127.0.0.1           @hekko

Comment: Have you set up a **network ACL**? It's a common problem with outgoing connections. If you don't know what I'm talking about, edit your question and add the result of `select * from dba_network_acls;`

Comment: hi @kfinity My network ACL is 100% fine. This is the reason I am able to connect to my WebSocket. My only problem is I am not able to receive or read message as message to follow WebSocket rfc6455 Protocol.

Answer (score 1):

check for data transfering WebSocket protocol

for exapmple:
HEXTORAW('810568656C6C6F'):

81 - byte for data begining

05 - length of text "hello"

68656C6C6F - "hello"

and of course don't raise exception before close connection.

```
DECLARE
    CONN         UTL_TCP.CONNECTION;
    RETVAL       BINARY_INTEGER;
begin
    CONN := UTL_TCP.OPEN_CONNECTION(
        REMOTE_HOST   => '127.0.0.1',
        REMOTE_PORT   => 5050,
        TX_TIMEOUT    => 10,
        charset     => 'UTF-8'
    );
    RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'GET / HTTP/1.1');
    RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Upgrade: websocket');
    RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Connection: Upgrade');
    RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Host: 127.0.0.1:5050');
    RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Origin: null');
    RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Sec-WebSocket-Key: TyPfhFqWTjuw8eDAxdY8xg==');
    RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13');
    RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN);
    BEGIN
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UTL_TCP.GET_Line(conn, false));  -- read handshake result
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN others THEN NULL;
    END;
    RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_RAW(conn,HEXTORAW('810568656C6C6F'));
    UTL_TCP.FLUSH(CONN);
    UTL_TCP.CLOSE_CONNECTION(CONN);
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm );
    UTL_TCP.CLOSE_CONNECTION(CONN);
end;
```

Comment: your code is almost there. just still not receiving any message on the server side.  Data Framing explained here: 

https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.1

Comment: test with java websockets, send and handle your json as: '815F7B22636C69656E7453657373696F6E223A2022726D6D64356B6663627637693368306A65656C353761346F3632222C226D657373616765223A202248692066726F6D206F7261636C65222C20226D7367436C69656E74223A2022706870227D'